# Troubles with while loop and mechanize Ruby

Tags: ruby, while-loop, mechanize

I don't understand why my ruby code doesn't work with while and mechanize.

```
require 'mechanize'
mechanize = Mechanize.new
j = 1
while j <= 30 do
    page = mechanize.get('http://mywebsite.com/events?page=#{j}'); j+=1
    i = 1
    while i <= 35 do
        link = page.link_with(:id => /detail-link-#{i}/); i += 1
        mylink = link.click
        url = mylink.uri
        title = mechanize.get(url)
        puts title.at('.container h1')
    end
end
```

My while loop `i` work but loop `j` doesn't go to the next page, I think my logic is not good but I don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to interpolate the page number into the page's URL. But interpolation only works with double quotes (`"`).

Change

```
page = mechanize.get('http://mywebsite.com/events?page=#{j}'); j+=1
```

to

```
page = mechanize.get("http://mywebsite.com/events?page=#{j}"); j+=1
```

Comment: thank you it works! i'm a beginner with ruby i didn't know interpolation only works with double quotes